# Pre-written main function for each base class

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, program-entry-point

Is there a sensible way to do the following:
There are many executables that will be written by myself and others, and many will be added far into the future. Each executable runs a derived class of a base Worker class. So there is Worker1, Worker2, Worker3, ..., and each executable will do a different task.

Even though each is different, their main function is always the same:

```
int main() {
    Worker1 myWorker;
    return myWorker.Initialize_And_Run();
}
```

Obviously that's not much typing, but I'd like to avoid the code-duplication in case the main function needs some more logic in the future. Also, I'm just curious if this is possible.

Is there a way to write a pre-written main function to avoid the duplication?

Thanks everyone for the help!

EDIT: simplified the code a bit

Comment: Seems like some form of inheritance should come into play here but I'm not sure how this plays out in terms of main(), or maybe a template?

Comment: Ya, I'm basically trying to template main(), but according to a Google search that's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a macro, which you can define on the command line.

```
int main()
{
    WORKER_TYPE myWorker;
    return myWorker.Initialize_And_Run();
}
```

In gcc, for example, you can compile this as follows:

```
g++ -D'WORKER_TYPE=Worker1' main.cpp -o main
```

And that will compile with `WORKER_TYPE` replaced by `Worker1`.

Comment: I was thinking it might come down to macros. Unless there's some really clever way of doing this, then that'll work just fine.